# LUKS on >2TB disk

Tags: encryption, disk, lvm, luks, gpt

I have a 3TB disk which I want to encrypt. As soon as I create a file system (mkfs.xfs or ext2-4) in the encrypted partition it outputs "Attempt to read block from file-system resulted in short read while creating root dir".

If I don't encrypt, this error doesn't appear and I can use the disk like expected.

I created a GPT partition table with parted like this:

```
# parted /dev/sdb
mklabel gpt
mk primary 0.00TB 3.00TB
quit
```

This worked fine.

I then created the crypt-container and decrypted it like this:

```
# cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdb
# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb1 storage
```

This worked, too.

Now I tried to create the file system:

```
# mkfs.xfs /dev/mapper/storage
```

This resulted in the following error: "Attempt to read block from file-system resulted in short read while creating root dir".

I tried to create a LVM-container and create the crypt-container inside. This works, but after copying some files on the disk it crashes and reports I/O-errors every time I try to access it.

I checked the disk for errors in Linux and with the Seagate-tool in Windows. No errors were found.

I experimented by creating <=2TB crypt-partitions and managed to create file-systems without errors. But when I resize the containers it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Bug report? Some sources indicate that error is often failing or sluggish disk, but given the inordinately large size of the disk I'm guessing bug report.  references: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.device-mapper.devel/14600  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=837867

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was caused by a failing disk. I wiped it several times and finally got an error after 105GB and the disk crashed.

I got a replacement and I could get it working on the first try. Also, I could wipe it until the last bit without an error. The last bit threw a "not enough disk space" error, though. Reliable. I don't know if I should be worried...

For everyone who has a similar problem: You can wipe your disk like this:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M
```

Make sure /dev/sdb is the right disk, you'll lose all your data on it! It should not display any error and end with a summary.